# Two text over a gradient image. Every element with a different link

Tags: html, css

I'm getting crazy to solve a situation.

I have an image with two titles. The titles are over the image that has also a gradient to improve readability.

Every title has a different link, the image is linked to another url.

```html
    <div>
     <a href="www.disney.com">
      <img alt="image" src="https://cdn.dday.it/system/uploads/cover_element/custom_image/1/prime_cov.jpg">
     </a>
     <div class="gradient"></div>
     <div class="title">
      <h2>
       <a href="www.example.com">First title </a>
       <a href="www.cnn.com">Second title</a>
      </h2>
     </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is that with the text over the image i cannot click to the separate link. I get always the image link. How can I solve?

I create a pen.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/robypez/pen/eKzKvN)

Comment: They aren’t clickable, because someone put `pointer-events: none;` on the div container element, duh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
pointer-events: none;
```

in your css.

This is preventing the click on title. Thus firing image href.
Remove that.

```css
.variant-4 #block-1 {
    width: 720px;
    height: 280px;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
}
.cover-block {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    width: 360px;
    height: 280px;
}

a {
    color: #1F1F1F;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
  color: white;
}

.cover-block .title {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "proxima-nova-extra-condensed", arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 18px 24px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover-block horizontal" id="block-1" >
  <a href="/redazione/26926/prime-music-italia">
    <img alt="image" src="https://cdn.dday.it/system/uploads/cover_element/custom_image/1/prime_cov.jpg"/>  </a>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <div class="title">
      <h2><a href="http://www.example.com">First title </a> <a href="http://www.cnn.com">Second title</a></h2>
      
    </div>
    

  <a class="comment comments-count-production-content-26926" data-disqus-identifier="production-content-26926" href="/redazione/26926/prime-music-italia#disqus_thread">17</a>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't noticed it. Sorry